# Lenovo Ideapad 5 Battery Health

Tags: power-management, battery

It's been a year since I'm using my Lenovo Ideapad 5 with Ubuntu as my primary os. However, recently I was concerned with the battery backup. The "energy design" is 56.5 Wh but "energy when full" is 47.5 Wh. Does it mean that my battery has degraded? Do I need to change the battery?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Let’s look at these questions in isolation:

**Q. Does it mean that my battery has degraded?**

Yes, but this isn’t something to worry about just yet. Batteries degrade all the time, either from use, abuse, and/or heat. The average battery is expected to last about three years but can go for many more if regularly cycled and discharged at a consistent rate (meaning, not gaming or mining bitcoin while on battery). Most of my Lenovo batteries are sitting at about 50% capacity after five years.

**Q. Do I need to change the battery?**

Only if the battery is unable to provide enough charge, meaning the battery shows something like 50% and then dies on you.